# Freeze a ui.Textbox in the panel in Google Earth Engine and make it active using a checkbox

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to Freeze (or remove) a ui.Textbox at first and then make it active after checking a box in the panel in Google Earth Engine?

I tried adding a function in the panel but I got an error.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6b19fdf51c0d993ef982c186e33841af